# SQL Server 2012 - password for services during silent installation

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am a database developer and I have a task to prepare silent installation of SQL Server 2012 using configuration file.
I have a problem with passwords for server services like: RSSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\ReportServer"

During normal installation with user interface there is no need to specify passwords for services. I assume that setup generates random passwords or they are handled by Windows virtual accounts.

However when I use configuration file then setup expect to provide a password either in the file or in the command prompt.

My question is why do I have to provide a password with silent installation while it is no needed during normal installation.
Is there a way to silently install SQL Server without specifying passwords for services?

Comment: Are you installing on a VM? Did you maybe complete one successful install and then reverted the VM to before that install and are now trying to run the script on the same VM?

Comment: Yes I am installing it on the VM. First I installed it from the user interface, then I uninstalled everything and now I try to install from script. I am using the same VM with Windows 2012.

Comment: I have seen that fail before. Somehow something still knows that that managed account had been created already and therefore now requires a password. Try your install script against a newly setup VM.

Comment: As @SebastianMeine suggested I tried to install it on a clean version of Windows on a new VM and it works.
Then I unistalled everything with SQL in name and tried to install it once again. And then I got the same error about password for services. So it looks like Windows is keeping info about managed account. I think a windows administrator could remove that managed account somehow, but it is ok for me to use clean install.

Comment: I copied my comment into an answer. Could you mark it as answer to help future readers out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to preserve this as an answer for future readers:

I have seen this type of failure before. Somehow something still knows that that managed account had been created already and therefore now requires a password.

Try your install script against a newly setup VM.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is why do I have to provide a password with silent installation while it is no needed during normal installation.

No, you should not provide the password for Virtual accounts. The `Password Parameter` should be left blank.

The reason for that is that the Virtual account is auto-managed and can access the n/w in a domain environment.

From [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx) :

> When you use a managed service account, virtual account, or a built-in account, you should not specify the corresponding password parameters.

[Virtual Accounts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx):

> Virtual accounts in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 are managed local accounts that provide the following features to simplify service administration. The virtual account is auto-managed, and the virtual account can access the network in a domain environment. If the default value is used for the service accounts during SQL Server setup on Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7, a virtual account using the instance name as the service name is used, in the format NT SERVICE\. Services that run as virtual accounts access network resources by using the credentials of the computer account in the format \$. When specifying a virtual account to start SQL Server, leave the password blank. If the virtual account fails to register the Service Principal Name (SPN), register the SPN manually.

Comment: I already have tried to put empty password in this way:  
RSSVCACCOUNT="NT Service\ReportServer"
RSSVCPASSWORD=""
but I got this error message: The specified value for setting 'RSSVCPASSWORD' is invalid. The expected value type is SqlSecureString.

Please tell me how to configure the ini file so no password is needed.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was slightly different but I had the same problem.  Was trying to use Managed Service Accounts in a SQL configuration file for unattended installation.  To make this work I removed the entries for the passwords altogether.  So in your example of ( RSSVCPASSWORD="" ), deleting the entire line allowed the install to complete.